# Highcharts: Positioning the toolip with chart.plotLeft

Tags: highcharts

In the highchart documentation is says:

> positioner: Function
>
> A callback function to place the tooltip in a default position. The callback receives three parameters: labelWidth, labelHeight and point, where point contains values for plotX and plotY telling where the reference point is in the plot area.
>
> *Add **chart.plotLeft** and **chart.plotTop** to get the full coordinates.*

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.positioner

But I'm not sure where I am supposed to add **plotLeft**, or **plotTop**

I don't see it on the scope, and I can't see it in the "chart" property options.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: It depends of the graphic

Comment: Are you doing bar ,oval can you show as what specific want because in the same page u can find demos

Comment: The positioner function should return the x and y coordinates of the position where you want your tooltip to appear considering the coordinates of the TopLeft of the chart to be  (0, 0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/j92p2/

```
    tooltip: {
        positioner: function (w, h, p) {
            var chart = this.chart,  // get chart
                plotLeft = chart.plotLeft, // get plotLeft
                plotTop = chart.plotTop;  // get plotTop

            console.log(this, plotTop, plotLeft); // watch console while hovering points

            return { x: 80, y: 50 };
        }
    }
```

See inline comments. Let me know if you have any more questions.